# Elastic Beanstalk with python 3.4 still using python 2.7

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just spin up some environment using EB with python 3.4 and Django but it keeps failing, looks like the error occurs when installing using `pip install -r requirements.txt` this are the events from the web console:

```
Time    Type    Details
2017-10-06 20:22:39 UTC-0600    WARN    Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Degraded. Command failed on all instances. Initialization completed 69 seconds ago and took 14 minutes.
2017-10-06 20:22:20 UTC-0600    ERROR   Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.
2017-10-06 20:21:17 UTC-0600    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2017-10-06 20:21:17 UTC-0600    ERROR   [Instance: i-0b46caf0e3099458c] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...) File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd) CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
2017-10-06 20:21:14 UTC-0600    ERROR   Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.
```

I followed this tutorial: [django-elastic-beanstalk-django](http://www.1strategy.com/blog/2017/05/23/tutorial-django-elastic-beanstalk/) and [deploying-a-django-app-and-postgresql-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk](https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-and-postgresql-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/) on both I'm stuck at the same step

Comment: use the latest AMI 2017-09 which supported Python 3

Comment: How can I use an AMI in Eb?

Comment: Find the AMI ID that you want to use. Then in EB replace the default AMI ID with the one that you want.

Comment: Could someone write out a slightly more complete set of instructions? Like go to the console and find an instance I already have and then use that AMI? I can find the AMI IDs of my instances via the EC2 console but it has `python34` in the ID. I'm getting the same errors with it trying to use `python2.7` when I deploy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had an exact same problem. Here is the solution I found:

1. **Go** to your env's **configuration**
2. **Click** the conf button of **Instances**
3. Under **Server** section, check your **Custom AMI ID**

For now, leave the page and go to [AWS EC2 Console page](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/)

4. Press **Launch Instance**
5. You will now be on **Step 1: Choose an Amazon Machine Image (AMI)**
6. Tada! You will see these ami ids that you can choose from:
   [image: AMI-IDs]
7. Go back to **no.3** and fill up the **Custom AMI ID**, refer from **no.6**
   (FYI, I used amazon linux, but it is up to you to decide)
8. Click **Apply** and wait till the configuration is done
9. Re-follow the **deploying django app**
10. **DONE!**