# AWS errors when installing requirements with python 2.7 when EB environment is python 3.6

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli, aws-ebs

How do I get the aWS EB instance to use the python 3 version that is already installed on the instance?
I can't get a new environment running with Python 3.6 running Django 2.1+.

**Local (not in virtual env):**

```
which python -> /usr/local/bin/python
python -V -> Python 2.7.15
which python3 -> /usr/local/bin/python3
python3 -V -> Python 3.6.5
which pip -> /usr/local/bin/pip
pip -V -> pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)`
which pip3 -> /usr/local/bin/pip3
pip3 -V -> pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

**Local in virtualenv `mstFirst`**:

```
which python -> /Users/me/.virtualenvs/mstFirst/bin/python
which python3 -> /Users/me/.virtualenvs/mstFirst/bin/python
python -V -> Python 3.6.5
python3 -V -> Python 3.6.5
which pip -> /Users/me/.virtualenvs/mstFirst/bin/pip
which pip3 -> /Users/me/.virtualenvs/mstFirst/bin/pip3
pip -V -> pip 18.0 from /Users/me/.virtualenvs/mstFirst/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
pip3 -V -> pip 18.0 from /Users/me/.virtualenvs/mstFirst/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
aws --version -> aws-cli/1.16.9 Python/3.6.5 Darwin/17.7.0 botocore/1.11.9
eb --version -> EB CLI 3.14.4 (Python 3.6.5)
eb -list -> * mst-p3
eb -config ->
  ApplicationName: mst
  DateUpdated: 2018-09-07 02:15:51+00:00
  EnvironmentName: mst-p3
  PlatformArn: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1::platform/Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.7.3
  settings: …
```

**Files**:

".elasticbeanstalk/config.yml"

```
branch-defaults:
  master:
    environment: mst-p3
environment-defaults:
  mst-p3: …
global:
  application_name: mst
  default_platform: 64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.7.3 running Python 3.6
  default_region: us-east-1
  workspace_type: Application
…
```

".ebextensions/01_packages.config"

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    python36: []
    python36-devel: []
    postgresql93: []
    postgresql93-devel: []
    mod24_ssl : []

commands:
  pip_upgrade:
    command: /opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
    ignoreErrors: false
```

Error when trying `eb deploy`, which points to wrong python version (2.7) while trying to run `pip install -r requirements.py`:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-jt3_s4in/slugger/
2018-09-07 03:28:35,315 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
    install_dependencies()
  File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
    check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 186, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

**Remote Instance ssh (`eb ssh`)**:

```
pyhthon -V -> Python 2.7.14
pyhthon3 -V -> Python 3.6.5
```

**Things I've tried:**

- Replacing the environment AMI with a current version and rebuilding per https://stackoverflow.com/a/47157777/1234721 , but the environment errors with an AMI of "ami-0ff8a91507f77f867" for "Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0 (HVM), SSD Volume Type"
- trying to hook into the YAML config to switch the python versions
- re-init using `eb init`
- verified my ssh keys per : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51669982/1234721

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused by the wrong version of pip (Python 3.x pip) in the Python 2.7 installation.

The AWS tools are written for Python 2.7

I am also not sure if aws cli or eb has been completely tested with pip 18.

Uninstall pip from the Python 2 directory.
Uninstall eb

Reinstall.

I recommend installing the AWS CLI first even if you are not using it. This will ensure that your Python environment is setup correct for AWS tools.

You did not specify the OS, so I cannot give you OS specific uninstall / install directions.

Answer (score 0):

Using `eb init` definitely works:

```
eb init -p "64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v2.7.3 running Python 3.6" ...
```

Then just remove all the python stuff from your `.ebextension` files.

For the `yum section`, all I use is:

```
packages:
  yum:
    postgresql94-devel: []
```

There should be no need to upgrade pip.

Comment: I have already tried re-initing to override, as well as from scratch.  Using your command, I get - `ERROR: NotFoundError - Platform "64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v2.7.0 running Python 3.6" does not appear to be valid` as the platform flag I think takes the name `python-3.6`, but it still fails with scaled back yum and config files.

Comment: Sorry, just updated to correct platform. AWS may not allow to use older versions when initializing, so the new version is v2.7.3. I have two applications running, which I recently had to move from 3.4 to 3.6. I did have to kill any running servers, and start all over with the clean `eb init`, for it works

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- backing up and delete .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml
- run: eb init
  You can then select python version 3.6 within eb init