# Upgrade Ruby on Python Elastic Beanstalk instance

Tags: python, ruby, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

my `ruby -v` is `ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-linux]` on my Python EB instance.

I need Ruby 2.2 to install sass.

How can I get ruby 2.2?

My .ebextensions has this:

```
packages:
  yum:
    ruby-devel: []
  rubygems:
    sass: []
```

But I still am only getting an old version of Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that have the same question and haven't yet resolved it.

```
packages:
    yum:
        ruby22: []
        ruby22-devel: []
container_commands:
    01-set_ruby22:
        command: "alternatives --set ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.2"
    02-install_sass:
        command: "gem install sass"
```

First, via **yum** we install the latest supported version of Ruby and Ruby Devel (I prefer 2.4, but the question is for 2.2), after, via *container_commands*, we set the current ruby version to the latest one, and later we install **sass**

I prefix the mumbers because it tells to container commands the order in which I need to run each command.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but can you try adding the ruby main version in the .ebextensions file?  I would recommend the latest version of ruby you can use, as of now it's 2.6 so perhaps:

```
packages:
  yum:
    ruby26-devel: []
  rubygems:
    sass: []
```

However, if this alone doesn't work, you will probably need to use the CLI, for more ideas see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52215189/aws-errors-when-installing-requirements-with-python-2-7-when-eb-environment-is-p)

Comment: I'm trying this, but for some reason ruby 2.0 is still being installed, meaning that both ruby 2.0 and ruby 2.2 are installed at the same time. Running `ruby -v` still outputs `ruby2.0.0`.

Comment: No, I'm using `yum` to manage packages on Elastic Beanstalk. Can I use RVM on Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 0):

ruby26-devel is probably not available in amazon linux repo yet. Try install `ruby22-devel` and run `alternatives --set ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.2`. You can run the commands in ebextensions